# issue with program executing infinately, java

Tags: java

the little method im working on is supposed to simulate a position starting at 0, then randomly steping back or going forward until either position 3 or position negative 3 is reached, while recording the highest position reached incase negative 3 is reached.

the method i have written here isnt working because its not properly stopping at -3 or 3.

```
public void randomWalk(){

    Random ran = new Random();
    int position = 0; 
    int max = 0; 
    int steps = 0; 
    while(position != 3 || position != -3){
        int r = ran.nextInt(2);

        if(position > max){
            max = position;
        } else if(r == 0){
           position += 1;
        }else{
            position -= 1 ; 
        }
        System.out.println("position = " + position);
    }
    System.out.println("max position = " + max);

}
```

i hope this is an acceptable question format.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `while (Math.abs (position) != 3)`

Comment: sorry i pasted a version fo my code where i didnt have the or operator in there, even with the above fix it executed infinately

Comment: Why do you need the `max` variable, this will be the same value as `position` when the loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Random ran = new Random();
int position = 0; 

while(Math.abs (position) != 3){

    int r = ran.nextInt(2);

    if(r == 0){
       position += 1;
    }else{
        position -= 1 ; 
    }
    System.out.println("position = " + position);
}
System.out.println("max position = " + position);
```

As per my comments above

Why do you need the max variable, this will be the same value as position when the loop ends.